# Java Difference between while and for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

Here are my codes about these two loops

```
int[] b = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8};
    int k=0;
    int h=b.length;
    int x=3;
    while(k<h){
        if(x>=b[k]){
            if(x < b[k+1]){
                System.out.println("k = " + k);
                break;
            }
        }
        else{
            k++;
        }
    }
```

Here is the for loop:

```
for(int k=0; k<h;k++){
        if(x>=b[k]){
            if(x < b[k+1]){
                System.out.println("k = " + k);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

But only for loop can get the right result. When I run the while loop, just never stop and println the result. I don't know why. I think they are same.

Comment: What happens if you step through it in debug mode?

Comment: Take the `k++` out of the else statement. There is no reason to have it conditioned. Simply put it at the bottom of the while loop.

Comment: Also, consider combing your if statements with `&&` and make sure you dont run outside the array index when you check for the next value.

Comment: What *is* the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

That's because in your `while` loop, the `k++` only happens in the `else` case. In your `for` loop, the `k++` always happens each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop is going forever because you only increment `k` in the `else` block. The `for` loop terminates because `k` is **ALWAYS** incremented, regardless of whether `k<h` is `true`.

Comment: Thank you. I figure out it.